# Taking infinite (binary) product in topological groups

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, topological-groups

Normally when we work in a group $G$, the pure algebraic structure doesn't allow us to make sense of infinite the infinite product $g_1g_2g_3...$ where $g_i\in G$. However, if we give $G$ a topology, this can change. A motivating example is $(\mathbb{Q},+)$, where $$1=\sum_\infty 2^{-n}$$
where we now have convergence of the infinite sum. I'm under the impression (I could be wrong) that even when talking about topological or Lie groups, we don't usually consider these sort of convergence issues. Is there a standard reference, or even name, for what these structures are?

Comment: I don't know much about this kind of thing but I was curious as well. I looked it up and apparently, Uniform Spaces are spaces that generalize topological groups and metric spaces so that standard analysis results still hold. It is quite different from the usual notions of infinite sums and products but it might still be relevant.

Comment: A large class of topological groups is Banach spaces, and more generally topological vector spaces, where summability issues have been widely studied. Abelian topological groups are quite well-handled too. The non-commutative case is more delicate since there are more way to sum, the most naive one being indexed by an increasing or decreasing sequence, but make sense indexed by more general totally ordered sets. (Sorry I'm not sure about references.)